# How to create a virtualgpkg in spatialite

Tags: spatialite, geopackage

I am currently using OGC GeoPackage features and tiles which is another spatial data format that is also a SQLite3 container.
I am using it in a mobile app but GeoPackage does not support spatial queries and spatial functions like SpatiaLite. I see there is a new feature of SpatiaLite that's a **virtualgpkg**. Like their virtual Shapefile.
Trying not to reinvent the wheel and take advantage of this cool feature and all the functionality.

In the [reference of SpatiaLite 4.2.0](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=4.2.0%20functions#8) the syntax for creating **virtualgpkg**  is:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE tablename USING module(arg1, ...);
```

I need more examples of the syntax. How it references a `GeoPackage Filename` and the `GeoPackage Tablename.`

Can someone provide the code to create a virtual GeoPackage table in SpatiaLite?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with just

`SELECT AutoGPKGStart()`

before the first usage, then

`SELECT AutoGPKGStop()`

when you are finished.

Those will create virtual tables for each GPKG table entry.

Comment: Did this work for you? If not, can you update your question with more details?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT AutoGPKGStart()` builds a wrapper to geom column but it doesn't create the view.

You need to do something like:

`CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE "vgpkg_<YOUR TABLE>" USING VirtualGPKG("YOUR TABLE")`